# RichTextBox SaveFile()

Tags: c++, richtextbox

How can I pass a string as a path into here

```
 void SaveLogFile()
         {              
             logTxt->SaveFile(String::Concat
                 (System::Environment::GetFolderPath
                (System::Environment::SpecialFolder::Personal),                                         
                 "\\Testdoc.rtf"), RichTextBoxStreamType::RichNoOleObjs);
         }
```

I can't figure out how to set a non SpecialFolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e.aspx):

```
void SaveMyFile()
   {
      // Create a SaveFileDialog to request a path and file name to save to.
      SaveFileDialog^ saveFile1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;

      // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the RTF extention for the file.
      saveFile1->DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
      saveFile1->Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

      // Determine whether the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog. 
      if ( saveFile1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK &&
         saveFile1->FileName->Length > 0 )
      {
         // Save the contents of the RichTextBox into the file.
         richTextBox1->SaveFile( saveFile1->FileName );
      }
   }
```

See how the `System::String^` is created here. Do it this way, too...